# App detected as malware when using EncryptedSharedPreferences

Tags: android

When using "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03"

and this code:

```
MasterKey masterKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context, MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS)
                    .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                    .build();
            encryptedSharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                    context,
                    "filename",
                    masterKey,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            );
```

If I drag the (release) .apk on my phone I get a notification about that Avast detects this App as malware. Also when installing it and doing a scan, it also detects it as malware.
If I do it without EncryptedSharedPreferences but with normal SharedPreferences it is all fine, no issues.

So the issue is most likely with EncryptedSharedPreferences.

Someone had a similar issue?
Someone knows how to handle this properly?

Comment: Do you really want to take Avast and consorts as references?

Comment: No of course not, but if the app is shown as malware might some customers get confused.

Comment: I suggest that you report your findings to Google here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:618647 so they can take the appropriate measures (either contacting Avast about the false positive or changing the code in the library to not trigger this condition).